# How to add web application (project from Visual Basic 2010) to Sharepoint Foundation

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, web-application

I would like to ask, how I can add web application (this is Visual Basic project) to my site collection in Sharepoit Foundation? Can I do this without create web part? If no or yes please tell me how I can do it?

Thanks for your support,
Andrzej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly you have a web application project built in Visual Basic and you intend to access it from within a SharePoint Foundation site, right?
Developing a web part for that should not be needed (unless other requirements must be fulfilled). For starter, is not actually the type of scenario SharePoint likes or is meant to work (by design, but also because the concept of site/web application in SharePoint has different meanings than regular web sites built simply for ASP.NET), but if you really want to keep using it, you could deploy your web application on the same IIS, and use the "Page Viewer" web part to create an iFrame loading your other site.

Of course, if authentication is an issue, you would need to tackle that as probably Windows Authentication is needed at least starting from SharePoint.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have project in Visual Basic and I would like to add it to my site in Sharepoint. Ok I try to do it in way which you show me but if i want to create web part, how I can do it? Do I use my Visual Basic project? Thank for your support

Comment: Creating a Web Part is not the way to go because that is not the intended purpose (unless the only thing it does is simply creating a iFrame which loads your site).

Comment: OK I understand, thanks for your help :) I have once more question, I would like to add to Sharepoint simple application which looks like database with interface to insert/delete data. This application is also make in Visual Basic. Does it's possible to add that application to Sharepoint? If yes, how?

Comment: It is via BCS - Business Connectivity Services that you could easily build up External Content Types and expose them via External Lists which would allow you all List items operations. Use SharePoint 2010 Designer for simplest start, really powerful too, no-code solutions to update Databases, mainly SQL, but others supported too.